# Show elements on click and hide others using .is(':visible')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to wrap my head around js/jQuery, but I'm struggling a bit. I created a little accordion that shows and hide text sections when I click on a section title. What I would like to do now is: when I click on the title of a hidden section, show this section and hide all others that are already open (so that only one text section at a time is visible. I tried to use .is(':visible'), but since I'm a complete noob, I am not sure how to go about this. Any pointers appreciated.

Here's my attempt. I no there are quite a few things wrong with this, but I don'T really know where to start.

```
            <div class="title"><a href="#">Section 1</a>        
            </div>

            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
            </div>

            <div class="title"><a href="#">Section 2</a>    
            </div>

            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
            </div>

            <div class="title"><a href="#">Section 3</a>
            </div>

            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.title').click(function(){

      if ($('.text').is(":visible") == false) { 
      $(this).next('.text').show();

        } 
        else {
            $(this).next('.text').hide();

  });
```

Comment: How does it behave right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really no need for an `if` statement, try this and let me know:

```html
<div class="title"><a href="#">Section 1</a>        
            </div>

            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
            </div>

            <div class="title"><a href="#">Section 2</a>    
            </div>

            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
            </div>

            <div class="title"><a href="#">Section 3</a>
            </div>

            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
            </div>

       

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.title').click(function(){
      $(this).siblings('.text').hide();
      $(this).next('.text').show();
  });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a million! I was so focused on the is.visible thing I didn't think of any other way!

Answer (score 0):

You can always use pure JavaScript:

To make the element appear:

```
document.getElementById('Your element ID').style = "display: block;"
document.getElementById('Your element ID').style = "visibility: visible;"
```

To make the element disappear:

```
document.getElementById('Your element ID').style = "display: none;"
document.getElementById('Your element ID').style = "visibility: invisible;"
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I combine this with the if condition? If [click on closed element] then [open closed element and close all other elements].

Answer (score 0):

You are doing all good just replace your if condition with `if($(this).next('.text').is(":visible") === false)`. Just check whether text of click div next is visible or not instead of checking all ".text" classes.(see below code)

```js
$('.text').hide();//if you want open all section at start remove this line

$('.title').click(function(){
  var visible=$(this).next('.text').is(":visible");
  $('.text').hide();
  if(!visible)
    $(this).next('.text').show();
    
  /*if ($(this).next('.text').is(":visible") === false) { 
    $(this).next('.text').show();
  } 
  else {
        $(this).next('.text').hide();
  }*/
});
```

```html
<div class="title"><a href="#">Section 1</a>        
            </div>

            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
            </div>

            <div class="title"><a href="#">Section 2</a>    
            </div>

            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
            </div>

            <div class="title"><a href="#">Section 3</a>
            </div>

            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, that already helped a lot. However, it doesn't close the open divs when I click on a closed div. Any idea how to fix this? What I need is: if [click on closed element] then [open closed element and close all othe openr elements].